# Can't find a way to view a post by their slug/title in flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Is their a way to view a post by their title instead of their id ?

i tried to get it show, but i been failing at it, and how would you slug them using slugifier or urlhelper, please forgive me, im still pretty new to python.

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/posts/<title>')
@login_required
def show(title):
    mytitle = Post
    link = db.session.query(mytitle).filter_by(title = title).one()
    return render_template("post.html", post=Post.query.get(id), pid=id, link=title)
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80))
    body = db.Column(db.Text)



    def __init__(self, title, body):
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
```

so im pretty much confused

Comment: `post=Post.query.get(id)` should probably be `post=link`.

Comment: THANKSSSSSS A TON MANNNNNNNNN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@app.route('/posts/<title>')
@login_required
def show(title):
    mytitle = Post
    link = db.session.query(mytitle).filter_by(title = title).one()
    return render_template("post.html", post=Post.query.get(id), pid=id, link=title)
```

for the above code to work like you want it to i would make a few changes,

1. `mytitle = Post` <== this line is totally unnecessary and kind of confusing, i would remove it
2. then you would need to change the refrences to `mytitle` to `Post`
   so change
   `link = db.session.query(mytitle).filter_by(title = title).one()`
   to
   `link = db.session.query(Post).filter_by(title = title).one()`
3. the real reason your not getting what you want though is the last line, specfically `post=Post.query.get(id)`, which is just loading the post by its id, even though i dont really see where its getting the id from, but yea, the main fix would be what the commentor suggested changing the part i just mentioned to `post=link` because your setting link to your current post.

so all together it should look like this:

```
@app.route('/posts/<title>')
@login_required 
def show(title):
    link = db.session.query(Post).filter_by(title = title).one()
    return render_template("post.html", post=link, pid=id, link=title)
```

Comment: THANKSSSSSS A TON MAN, i was stuck on this for hours, how would i slug this, is my next question kyle

Comment: i would use the `inflection` library, then you can say  `mypost.slug = inflection.titleize(unicode(mypost.title))`

Comment: if you want to put it as a new question, let me know and ill explain more thoroughly in the answer

Comment: yeah, im going to spend some time on getting this right, i dont want to be a pain in the ass, because the lack of resources of learning for flask.